# Handle Needed For Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, handle, firemonkey

How can i set the handle needed property for a form in firemonkey. In normal delphi I use to create forms inside other components at run time. IE:

```
Form1 := TForm1.Create(Panel1);
Form1.Parent := Panel1;
Form1.HandleNeeded;
```

But now in Firemonkey there are no Handles per say. So is there another way i can do this.
It is pretty essential that it has the parent Panel1 as the form has to only show in panel1 and no where else on the screen

Comment: Does the handle really need to be explicitly created here? I would try just commenting out that statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FMX if you want one form to be displayed inside another:

On the child form, add any controls inside a container (e.g. a TLayout). Create the child form. Set the Parent property of the TLayout (etc.) to the parent form (or, more probably a container on the parent form so you can set the child TLayout's alignment to alClient).

Answer (score 1):

Thats what i am trying, but the form still apears as an independet form. not in the layout:

```
TNewLogin:=TFrmLogin.Create(Self);
TNewLogin.Parent:=Layout1;
TNewLogin.Show;
```